# Как удалить сглаживание на элементе Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть такой код на javascript:

```
function updateGrid()
{
  cntx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  cntx.lineCap = 'butt';
  cntx.lineWidth = 1;
  for(var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++)
  {
      cntx.beginPath();
      cntx.moveTo(x * cellSize + move.x, move.y);
      cntx.lineTo(x * cellSize + move.x, canvas.width * cellSize+move.y);
      cntx.stroke();  
      cntx.closePath()
  }
}
```

Предполагается, что он нарисует `canvas.width` **белых** линий, толщиной в **один** пиксель. Но получается то, что на скриншоте:

[image]

На каком-то форуме прочитал, что может помочь убирание строчки `cntx.beginPath();`. Но без неё рисуется что-то еще более странное:

[image]

На другом форуме сказали, что ширина линии может быть меньше единицы. На следующей картинке ширина `.0`, без строки `cntx.beginPath();`:
[image]

А это с ней:

[image]

Скажите, как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

При попытке нарисовать линию шириной в `1px`, используя координаты `x=(1, 0);` `y=(1, 3);` будет охвачено по `0.5px` с каждой стороны линии, в результате чего, она будет иметь ширину `2px`.

Это происходит из-за неспособности дисплея отобразить пол-пиксиля.

[image: Given]

---

Для того, чтобы вывести линию шириной в `1px` нужно вычислять коориданаты с пол- пикселя, т.е вместо `x=(1, 0);` `y=(1, 3);` будет `x=(1.5, 0);`  `y=(1.5, 3)`

В результате браузер будет рисовать линию охватывая по `0.5px` с каждой стороны, тем самым получая линию в `1px`.

[image: Result]

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9uq3k7w2/). Первая линия имеет цвет `#ffffff`, а вторая `#808080`. Разница только в координатах.

---

Различия в цветах происходят из-за сглаживания, которое упомянуто в вопросе.

[image: antialiasing]

Когда линия проходит через пол-пикселя, он окрашивается в серый цвет, иначе изображение будет зубчатым. Цвет пикселя выбирается в процессе сглаживания, при котором учитывается гамма. Пиксели будут окрашены в промежуточный цвет между цветом изображения и цветом фона.

Аналогичные действия происходят и в вашем случае.

В данном случае отключить сглаживание нельзя, это было бы возможно в случае использования `drawImage`.

---

[Canvas - Dive Into HTML5](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/canvas.html)

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, размеры канваса вы задаете через стили, а надо через атрибуты элемента `canvas`.

```
<canvas width="100" height="200"></canvas>
```

В ином случае изображение растягивается из размера по умолчанию.

**Еще одна особенность**: на экранах *retina* удвоенное количество точек, поэтому размер для таких экранов нужно уменьшать: в атрибутах ставить, например, `width="200"`, а в стилях `width:100px`

**Добавлю:**

Есть еще одна особенность, когда вы рисуете линию она появляется с координатами между двумя пикселями. Поэтому вам нужно либо к вашим координатам прибавлять 0.5:

```
context.lineTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
```

Или сделать так:

```
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```