# Чем заменить канву в js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте. Так как на мой предыдущий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560422/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5) никто не отвечает, думается, что стандартная канва не предназначена для рисования тонких линий (или, может, я неправильно вопросы задаю?). В связи с этим, вопрос - есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая умела бы тоже самое, что и стандартная канва, но так, чтобы толщиной линий и их цветом (и, судя по всему, сглаживанием) можно было легко управлять?

Comment: Я вам в том вопросе ответил.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте с SVG поработать, тоже самое только в векторе, а не растре

Answer (score 0):

Есть adobe Animate CC - там визуальная работа с канвасами, нарисуйте что вам нужно, экспортируйте в html+js и разберитесь по коду. В нативном виде все будет подробно расписано ибо реализация возможна очень большим кол-вом способов.